# php preg_match_all custom pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have one string like

```
$string = ">xyz, >abc hi there and also hi to >nrm";
```

I want to find all occurrences of words which are next to ">" sign
for example in above string it would return all words xyz, abc and nrm

I tried some ways but no any result

Help me guys and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
preg_match_all("/>(\w+)/", $string, $matches);
// $matches[1] contains the matches you want.
```

See also: [Example of it in action on Ideone](http://ideone.com/kFagk)